# Why are my <h1> and <p> tags on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I am not able to get my p tag text off from the same line as my h1 tag

At the moment it looks like this:

```
**Title**paragraph
```

And I would like it like this:

```
**Title**
paragraph
```

HTML and CSS:

```css
.texttitle {
    font-family: Serif;
    height: 90vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    animation: color-change 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes color-change {
    0% { color:#CE9FFC ; }
    25% { color: #8C1BAB; }
    50% { color:#2411ee; }
    75% { color:#8C1BAB; }
    100% { color:#CE9FFC; }
  }
```

```html
<div class="texttitle">
      <h1 class="title"><strong>Title</strong></h1>
      <p class="paragraph">paragraph under title</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the expected result when using `display: flex;` on `.texttitle`.

Comment: add `flex-direction: column` to `.texttitle`

Comment: tysm, really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Declaring .texttitle `{display: flex;}` has made that div into a flex container. As such, your `<h1>` and `<p>` are flex items. The default flex direction is row and therefore your two flex items are aligning on the same row.

If the `<h1>` and `<p>` are the only two items you will have in the .texttitle div then you can simply add

```
flex-direction: column;
```

to your .texttitle CSS.

Answer (score 1):

See here what's actually happening. By giving

```
.texttitle {
    display: flex;
}
```

You are making your div a flex-box, and in flex-box, the child elements by default align as rows that is horizontal.

Default value of flex-direction in flex-box is

```
flex-direction : row;
```

now make it align vertically by setting

```
flex-direction : column;
```

in your class texttitle.

In your code, you can also  achieve your desired alignment by removing  the display:flex;
from the class texttitle

```
display: flex
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you add both of tags in flex containers which class is texttitle. in default flex containers all elements display side by side. if you want display other elements a new line, add this property in texttitle class:

```
flex-direction : column;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.texttitle {
    font-family: Serif;
    height: 90vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    animation: color-change 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes color-change {
    0% { color:#CE9FFC ; }
    25% { color: #8C1BAB; }
    50% { color:#2411ee; }
    75% { color:#8C1BAB; }
    100% { color:#CE9FFC; }
  }
```

```html
<div class="texttitle">
      <h1 class="title"><strong>Title</strong></h1>
      <p class="paragraph">paragraph under title</p>
</div>
```